# Can't read from my external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I've tried to connect my HD after a while, and it stated that I need to format it, which obviously I don't want to since I have files in it..
I've tried to look for a solution, and found the program 'TestDisk', that told me that I have a 'damaged file system' over there.
After that, I've accidently clicked on the 'write' command in the program(write partition sctructure to disk), that asked me later to reconnect the HD.
From now on, when connecting the HD, it doesn't even show up in 'My PC'.

The HD does show up in device manager, and also on 'disk management', and it states 'Unallocated', and the only thing I can do to it is to initialize it.
After some digging, I wanted to check if I can see it through my BIOS, but when trying to restart my laptop with the HD connected, the laptop just won't start.
So I've tried to enter the BIOS without the HD connected, and connect it while in the BIOS, the laptop got freeze, and there was nothing I could do except for disconnect it.
TestDisk also doesn't recognize the HD anymore, it shows only the one that in my laptop.

I'm sorry for writing too much, just wanted to give as much information I could have.

Is there any way to get the data from the HD?

Update:As @AdamWykes suggested, a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA9Qe.png) is attached after getting info using 'CrystalDiskInfo'.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AdamWykes, though it was obvious.. If there's any way to get the data back

Comment: It's not obvious. You might have wanted that, or you might have wanted simply to get your laptop booting with the drive attached, etc.

Comment: The SMART test shows your disk is dead/dying.

Comment: Depending on how valuable the data on the drive is, it may be recoverable. If it is very valuable, there are services that can retrieve data from even dead drives. They cost a lot though, and there is no guarantee of data recovery. If the data is not worth hundreds of dollars though, then yes, your drive is likely dead.

Answer (score 1):

Not very much information is provided on the exact nature of the mistake made in TestDisk or the manner in which the drive came to need formatting to begin with. That error can arise a number of ways. Some of the most common ways are that the filesystem it is using isn't recognized by the OS trying to access the drive. Are you sure this is not the case?

In any case, assuming the filesystem of the external drive became corrupt or overwritten (which is why you would use TestDisk usually), you also seem to have performed an overwrite with TestDisk itself, by writing recovered data back to the same drive you took it from.

The drive now reads as unallocated, which means some damage has also occurred to its partition table, such that the partitions on the drive which were present are no longer readable by your OS. You will want to pay careful attention to the advice/instructions at http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step to attempt a recovery of the partition table. After the table is recovered you can attempt to recover files off the drive, either using TestDisk or some other means of your choice.

Since the drive shows up in the OS, you may assume BIOS detects it.

Addendum: If possible, use software like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) to help you determine whether or not the drive's hardware may be at fault for all this trouble. If the SMART data is showing imminent failure, it may no longer be prudent to trust this drive with your data.

Comment: The 'write' command I used on TestDisk stated 'write partition strture to disk' if it helps by any chance.. Also, TestDisk no longer recognize the drive when running it, only the HD inside my laptop

Comment: I've just added a screenshot using the software you suggested, CrystalDiskInfo.

Comment: Like others have already said, your drive is dead. You may not be able to retrieve data at all from it.